# Wicket doesn't encode correctly pair of two characters

Tags: xml, encoding, wicket

Coulnd't find better question so sorry for that and sorry for my bad english.

So I'm using wicket to read my messages from xml file. "ż" and "ó" are a polish letter.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
<entry key="wrongENcode">inżynierów</entry>
</properties>
```

html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html ...>
<wicket:extend>
<div class="someClassForwrongENcode"><h3><wicket:message key="wrongENcode"></wicket:message></h3></div>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

css:

```
.someClassForwrongENcode{
    position:relative;
    left:40px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
}
```

With this i'm getting this one:

[image: wrong encoding]

But If I change in my xml file

```
<entry key="wrongENcode">iżynierów</entry>
```

I will get this:

[image: correct encoding]

So it seems like it is encoding my polish letters correctly ("ż" and "ó") but If I add "n" before "ż", wicket won't encode it. I couldn't find an answer, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: 1. check if the file is really encoded in utf8; 2. Application#getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("utf-8"); 3. add the 'meta' tag to the HTML: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />